# Microsoft VPN Network

Tags: vpn

We are working on some proof of concept project.

We have some clients those are outside of the our company network. We incorporated each clients into our network through Microsoft VPN. Each client joined same network that's ok. But I just want to close all network traffics except http(s) 80, 443 on this created VPN network to protect each connected client's privacy, public folder access etc.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Cheers

**Update :**

The question is, is there any way to block network traffic except port 80, 443 on VPN adapter of connected client ?

Comment: And the question is...?

Yes, it can be done (but they won't be able to access file shares or other services on your network if you restrict them to http/s).

Comment: @fyasar Why use a VPN if they're only going to be accessing websites? Seems like it would be a lot easier to just have the website publicly facing with encryption and authentication.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is of course you can block or simply deny traffic on anytyhing put the standard HTTP and HTTPS ports.  However, as others have pointed out why would you want to do this?

HTTPS traffic in particular is fairly secure and runs over the same level of encryption that most VPN tunnels can offer and in some cases offer greater levels of encryption that certain VPN tunnels.  If you simply want to make internal sites available over the internet simply make them all HTTPS and then require Windows Authentication to access them.  It doesn't get much more secure than that and is most likely the simplest thing you can possibly do.

If my understanding isn't right then update your question to be more specific.